# keep a checkbox true after a display error message?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

How can I keep a checkbox true when i display error message? Every time I display a errorMessage my checkBox turn false. How can I solve this problem? I am using jsf2.0 and primefaces.

This is the button that calls a method:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="btIcon" 
                             value="Consolidar"
                             image="addIcon"
                             process="@this :formCadastro"
                             actionListener="#{bean.addConsolidacao}"
                             onclick="carregando.show();"
                             oncomplete="carregando.hide();" 
                             rendered="true" 
                             update="@this :formCadastro :formPanel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your submission is rejected when it fails validation and when you refresh, it refreshes to the old value. I believe you'll have to either code something client side or rethink how validation works.

Comment: I've chenged the tag like this: <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="ui-checkBox"  valueChangeListener="#{bean.select}"  value="#{true}"/> nevertheless the checkbox is not checked any time.

Comment: One way I've seen this resolved was by not refreshing the field itself, but rather refresh a hidden field with either a success or failure message. On refresh, check if the field is there, and if it is a success, it refreshes the panel. If unsuccessful, it only refreshes the error message control. That may not be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try process :formPanel too, maybe it works. But for an exact answer I must see your all code.

Comment: I've realized the problem, when the page is redenred the checkBox isn't part of the entity. Tthe solution is just set a transient on the entity in order to manipulate it.